# CSS styling of the footer goes wrong

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

and thanks in advance for your help.

I'm using a wordpress theme (called Eventr). In this theme, the footer has the id "footer":

```
<footer id="footer">
```

And the css stylesheet has the matching #footer element styled accordingly :

```
#footer {
color: #b0b0b0 !important;
background: #262626 !important;
padding-top: 70px !important;
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
}
```

However, although it seems to be working just fine in their demo (http://themeforest.net/item/eventr-one-page-event-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12212783), on my website the styling doesn't work at all. It looks as though the page entirely ignores the #footer styling elements : when I inspect the page, it isn't even called for :
    [screenshot of the page inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q40HK.jpg)

This puzzles me entirely. Any idea?

Cheers :)
Camille

PS: in the css stylesheet, I added the !important manually to see whether it would make any difference, but it makes none whatsoever.

Comment: Can you add a codepen or snippet?

Comment: are you able to provide live url ?

Comment: Are you running any caching plugins whilst doing CSS changes?

Comment: Please provide link to your CSS file.

Comment: How do you include your css? It's recommended that you do it in functions.php  with wp_enqueue_style() function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why aren't you contacting the theme's author?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of #footer just use footer and write your css i think it will work